# Three.js - remove objects from array dynamically created in loop

Tags: three.js

I am using three.js to create an animation of 'falling donuts'. These donuts are generated dynamically at every scene render and are pushed in an array.

Each donut is created with a random starting x position and velocity and but they should all start at the top of the screen and then move down vertically until they reach a certain point of the screen where I want these to be deleted/removed. While I can remove the object from the scene easily I am struggling to remove the reference from the array which just grows bigger at every render and would like to optimize in some way. Is there any other approach or solution to this? I am very new to threejs and relatively new to javascript too. Thanks in advance :)))

This is my mainloop function:

```
let donuts = [];

let mainLoop = function() {

    //create donut with a starting position and add to donuts array
    donuts.push(createDonut());

    donuts.forEach((donut)=>{
        scene.add(donut);
        donut.position.y += gravity * Math.random(); 

        if(donut.position.y <=  -1) {
            donut.geometry.dispose();
            donut.material.dispose();
            scene.remove(donut);
        }
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestId = requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a JavaScript perspective, you're adding donuts to the `donuts` array with `.push()` but you're never removing them from the array, only from the scene. So, of course your array is going to keep growing infinitely. You also shouldn't remove elements from an array when inside its own `forEach` loop. For example, if you start with 10 items, start the loop, then remove an element, your loop will still try to count to 10 but now you only have 9 elements!

From a Three.js perspective, you should not delete and re-generate objects this way because they're going to slow down your performance and possibly create memory leaks, so your page will consume more and more memory as time goes by.

Instead, it's standard practice to initialize the geometries you'll need at the beginning, and then you just re-use them as much as possible. Something like this:

```
let donuts = [];

// Initialize 20 donuts once
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    // Create donut at a random y-position between 10-20
    let newDonut = createDonut();
    newDonut.y = Math.random() * 10 + 10;

    donuts.push(newDonut);
    scene.add(newDonut);
}

let mainLoop = function() {
    donuts.forEach((donut)=>{
        donut.position.y += gravity * Math.random(); 

        if(donut.position.y <=  -1) {
            // Reset random Y position to use again
            donut.position.y = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
        }
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestId = requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! really helpful explanation :)